# BlazorWebAssembly - StateHasChanged not working with SignalR Response

Tags: apache-kafka, blazor, signalr

We have a Blazor WebAssembly app in .Net 7.0 that calls an API. This API publishes a message to a Kafka "Request" instance which processes the incoming message.
A MicroService picks up this Kafka message and processes it which then produces a ResultMessage that is written to a Kafka "Result" topic.
When a listener on the server consumes the Kafka "Result" message, it invokes a SignalR callback to the Blazor (browser) app.
The app successfully gets the returned message and invokes a method (`ShowPurchaseResponse`) within the Blazor App to populate some fields in the UI.
We have verified that the server side works as expected, and that the browser app successfully populates the fields that are supposed to show on the form.
The last line in the method (`ShowPurchaseResponse`) that processes the returned message in the browser is `StateHasChanged()`.However, the data is never displayed in the UI. We have tried `ShouldRender();` followed by `StateHasChanged()`, with no joy.
We have also tried `InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());` as per some StackOverflow suggestions, but still no joy.
We have set breakpoints in the `ShowPurchaseResponse` method and verified that data is present, it just never renders in the UI.
Our app has two "pages", and if we do not switch pages, the initial page works as expected, however when we switch to the second page and back to the first, all of our breakpoints are hit, but nothing ever changes in the UI.
The code for the various methods are shown below. We have a stateful process that is involved with the incoming message, and we found that the SignalR method was being called multiple times since it appears that the registration of the callback method was called every time the `OnInitializedAsync` method was invoked (every time we switched to this page). This caused our code in `GetPurchaseResultFromSignalR` to be called again which messed up our stateful process, so we added a static bool `isPageRegisteredWithSignalR` to ensure that two handlers were not registered in our `signalRClient` method.
Any help or clarification is gladly accepted. The real question is "Why does `StateHasChanged()` not force a render of the data when the data is returned from SignalR?"

Code for SignalRClient

```
public IDisposable ProcessOrderResult(Action<byte[]> action)
{            
    return _hubConnection.On(nameof(ProcessOrderResult), action);
}
```

Code for OnInitializedAsync

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    _purchaseRequest = MakeEmptyPurchaseModel();
    _state!.OnChange += StateHasChanged;

    //
    // Invoke the auth state delegate to get the logged in user.
    //
    var authState = await authenticationStateDelegate!;
    if (authState == null)
    {
        _navManager!.NavigateTo("/login");
    }

    //
    // Capture the method that the SignalR server
    // will invoke - this opens a channel to that server.
    // The SignalR Client class is a subclass of the
    // generic SignalR base class, but the 'ProcessOrderResult'
    // method is defined in the specific interface for
    // the _signalRClient. The Action that is
    // defined here actually is invoked when the SignalR
    // server sends a message down to this client.
    //

    if (!_isPageRegisteredWithSignalR)
    {
        _isPageRegisteredWithSignalR = true;
        _signalRClient.ProcessOrderResult(async (message) =>
        {
            var purchaseResponse = await _processService.GetPurchaseResultFromSignalR(message);
            if (purchaseResponse is not null)
            {
                ShowPurchaseResponse(purchaseResponse);
            }
        });

    }
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

Code for GetPurchaseResultFromSignalR

```
public async Task<PurchaseResponseModel> GetPurchaseResultFromSignalR(byte[] encodedResponse)
{
    //
    // Reveal the actual returned Json with our RevealHelper
    //
    var purchaseResponse = await _payloadService.Reveal<PurchaseResponseModel>(Convert.ToBase64String(encodedResponse));          
 

    return purchaseResponse;
}
```

Code for ShowPurchaseResponse

```
private void ShowPurchaseResponse(PurchaseResponseModel purchaseResponse)
{
    _purchaseResponse = purchaseResponse;
    _displayPrice = _purchaseResponse.Price.ToString("C");
    _displayOrderPlaced = _purchaseResponse.ReceivedAt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    if (!purchaseResponse.Success)
    {
        _purchaseResponse.Amount = 0;
    }
    _displayAmount = _purchaseResponse.Amount.ToString("C");
    if (_purchaseResponse.Success)
    {
        _alertService!.Info($"Purchase Request received from the Kafka environment - {_purchaseResponse.Message}.");
    }
    else
    {
        _alertService!.Warning($"Purchase Request received from the Kafka environment - {_purchaseResponse.Message}.");
    }
    ShouldRender();
    InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
    //StateHasChanged();     
}
```

Html for the Blazor Page

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Result</label>
    @if (_purchaseResponse != null)
    {
        <p>@_purchaseResponse.Message</p>
        <label>PO Number:</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" readonly="true" @bind-Value="_purchaseResponse.OrderNumber" />
        <label>Order Placed:</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" readonly="true" @bind-Value="_displayOrderPlaced" />
        <label>Price per unit:</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" readonly="true" @bind-Value="_displayPrice" />
        <label>Order total cost:</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" readonly="true" @bind-Value="_displayAmount" />
    }
</div>
```

Code for the entire "Page"

```
@page "/dataentry"
@implements IAsyncDisposable

<PageTitle>Publishing Data</PageTitle>

<h3>Purchase Request to Publish</h3>
<div class="alert alert-info">
    Enter an order to publish to Kafka for processing from @_state.LoggedInUser.Email.
    Once the order is processed, the status will show on this form - this may take
    some time since it is a complicated process on the API server to actually
    perform all of the work. The server is not blocked during the process
    as it is handled by a microservice which then informs the client via
    a SignalR callback when the process is finally completed.
</div>

<EditForm Model="@_purchaseRequest" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer Id</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="_purchaseRequest.CustomerNumber" class="form-control" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _purchaseRequest.CustomerNumber)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Product Id</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="_purchaseRequest.SKU" class="form-control" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _purchaseRequest.SKU)" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Quantity</label>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="_purchaseRequest.Quantity" class="form-control" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _purchaseRequest.Quantity)" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn my-2 btn-outline-primary" style="width:fit-content">
        @if (_processing)
        {
            <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
        }
        Place Order
    </button>
    <ValidationSummary />
    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_error))
    {
        <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3 mb-0">@_error</div>
    }
</EditForm>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Result</label>
    @if (_purchaseResponse != null)
    {
        <p>@_purchaseResponse.Message</p>
        <label>PO Number:</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" readonly="true" @bind-Value="_purchaseResponse.OrderNumber" />
        <label>Order Placed:</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" readonly="true" @bind-Value="_displayOrderPlaced" />
        <label>Price per unit:</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" readonly="true" @bind-Value="_displayPrice" />
        <label>Order total cost:</label>
        <InputText class="form-control" readonly="true" @bind-Value="_displayAmount" />
    }
</div>
<AlertMessage />
@code {
    [Inject] NavigationManager? _navManager { get; set; }
    [Inject] IAlertService? _alertService { get; set; }
    [Inject] IConfiguration? _config { get; set; }
    [Inject] IClientOrderProcessingService? _processService { get; set; }
    [Inject] ISignalRClient? _signalRClient { get; set; } // The class that wraps the SignalR transmission code.
    [Inject] Models.StateContainer? _state { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationStateDelegate { get; set; }

    private ClaimsPrincipal? _user;
    private string? _error { get; set; }
    private bool _processing { get; set; }
    private PurchaseModel _purchaseRequest { get; set; }
    private PurchaseResponseModel _purchaseResponse { get; set; }
    private string _displayAmount { get; set; }
    private string _displayPrice { get; set; }
    private string _displayOrderPlaced { get; set; }

    private static bool _isPageRegisteredWithSignalR { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When this page is initialized, it checks to be sure
    /// you are logged in.  If not, it directs to the login page.
    /// If you are, it gets the first page of data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        _purchaseRequest = MakePurchaseModel();
        _state!.OnChange += StateHasChanged;

        //
        // Invoke the auth state delegate to get the logged in user.
        //
        var authState = await authenticationStateDelegate!;
        if (authState == null)
        {
            _navManager!.NavigateTo("/login");
        }

        //
        // Capture the method that the SignalR server
        // will invoke - this opens a channel to that server.
        // The SignalR Client class is a subclass of the
        // generic SignalR base class, but the 'ProcessOrderResult'
        // method is defined in the specific interface for
        // the _signalRClient. The Action that is
        // defined here actually is invoked when the SignalR
        // server sends a message down to this client.
        //
        // https://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-core/realtime-app-using-blazor-webassembly-signalr-csharp9
        //

        if (!_isPageRegisteredWithSignalR)
        {
            _isPageRegisteredWithSignalR = true;
            _signalRClient.ProcessOrderResult(async (message) =>
            {
                var purchaseResponse = await _processService.GetPurchaseResultFromSignalR(message);
                if (purchaseResponse is not null)
                {
                    ShowPurchaseResponse(purchaseResponse);
                }
            });

        }
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// When the form is submitted, if all edits pass, this is invoked.
    /// This method calls into the processService to actually process
    /// the order request by sending it to the API.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        _processing = true;
        try
        {
            _purchaseRequest.OrderedAt = DateTime.Now;
            _alertService!.Info("Publishing purchase request to the Kafka environment.");
            if (await _processService.ProcessTheOrderRequest(_state.ConversationId, _state.LoggedInUser.ClientToken, _purchaseRequest))
            {
                _alertService!.Info("Purchase Request was published to the Kafka environment.");
            }
            else
            {
                _alertService!.Error("Purchase Request was NOT published to the Kafka environment.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _error = "Publish to Kafka failed.";
        }
        finally
        {
            _processing = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is the "callback" from SignalR. When the API
    /// sends back a response, this method is invoked via SignalR
    /// so the results of the purchase request are shown on this form.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="purchaseResponse">The payload that was received from SignalR.</param>
    private void ShowPurchaseResponse(PurchaseResponseModel purchaseResponse)
    {
        _purchaseResponse = purchaseResponse;
        _displayPrice = _purchaseResponse.Price.ToString("C");
        _displayOrderPlaced = _purchaseResponse.ReceivedAt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        if (!purchaseResponse.Success)
        {
            _purchaseResponse.Amount = 0;
        }
        _displayAmount = _purchaseResponse.Amount.ToString("C");
        if (_purchaseResponse.Success)
        {
            _alertService!.Info($"Purchase Request received from the Kafka environment - {_purchaseResponse.Message}.");
        }
        else
        {
            _alertService!.Warning($"Purchase Request received from the Kafka environment - {_purchaseResponse.Message}.");
        }
        ShouldRender();
        InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
        //StateHasChanged();     
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Just a helper method to build up a purchase model
    /// for testing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private PurchaseModel MakePurchaseModel()
    {
        return new PurchaseModel
            {
                CustomerNumber = $"CN-{DateTime.Now.Millisecond}",
                OrderedAt = DateTime.Now,
                Quantity = DateTime.Now.Minute,
                SKU = $"SKU-{DateTime.Now.Second}"
            };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the event for capturing the change of state.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        //_state!.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have made the mistake of registering a handler for the signalr incoming message but not removing it when you switch pages. You use a static field to prevent re registering, so the new page instance doesn't register to handle the incoming messages

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I did not realize I had to de-register the handler - it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that the render events built into the `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}` sequence, and any you add, have all completed by the time the data you want to display has been updated.  The difficulty is establishing why.

I can't see it, but there's no valid reason for:

```cs
// doesn't do anything
ShouldRender();
// NO
InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
// Not needed the render process will call it for you when the `OnInitialized{Async}/OnParametersSet{Async}` sequence completes. 
//StateHasChanged();
```

To debug these these types of problems you need to establish the actual running order that code is executing.  You can't use breakpoints because you're dealing with Asynchronous code.  You have to resort to the writing lines to the output/console.

In your component add a Uid to identify the component instance.  This helps you establish that you are dealing with the same instacne, and not creating new instances.

```cs
@code {
    private Guid Uid = Guid.NewGuid();
    //...
}
```

You can add this to the rendered content to see when the page is actually rendered:

```
@page "/"

@{
    Console.WriteLine($"Component - {Uid} - Rendered");
}
```

And this to see when you make render requests.  You won't capture the first this way as `ShouldRender` isn't called on the intitlai render.

```
@code {
    protected override bool ShouldRender()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Component - {Uid} - Render Queued");
        return base.ShouldRender();
    }
    //....
}
```

You can add similar writeline statements into your code blocks to track them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this guided me in the right direction. I added a method in my SignalRClient class on the browser to de-register the handler.
     public void RemoveProcessAuditDataResult()
        {
            _hubConnection.Remove(nameof(ProcessAuditDataResult));
        }
And I call it from my DisposeAsync method in the razor page.
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _signalRClient.RemoveProcessAuditDataResult();
        _signalRClient.RemoveProcessAuditTopicResult();
        _state!.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
It now works!

Comment: NP.  Glad to of assistance.